# Javascript - showing a commandLink and then Disappearing

Tags: javascript, css, jsf

I am working on a JSF application and want a simple function- click commandbutton and show a commandLink. I have done a test. The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function testfunc() {
     document.getElementById("testForm:test").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("testForm:test").style.visibility="visible";
   }
   </script>
 </head>

<body>

   <h:form id = "testForm" >
     <h:panelGroup id="test" style="display:none" >
          <h:commandLink value="Page 1" action="page1" /><br/>
     </h:panelGroup>
     <button onclick="testfunc()">Click me</button>
  </h:form> 

 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the link - `<h:commandLink value="Page 1" action="page1" />` is shown  immediately disappears.  Does anyone have any suggestion? Many thanks!

Comment: I tried but it does not work. The link does not show at all. Another thing, the file is a .xhtml file and run on Tomcat.

Comment: button being submit by default, kept submitting whole form. Please have a look at my answer to check

Comment: Thanks,  I think it is the reason. Another question - if it is possible to place button by h:commandButton?

Comment: yes u can. but remember to use type="button", there too. Can u choose my answer && upvote if everything works?

Comment: 3 upvotes and 1 favorite? wow... good question. And how is this 'jsf' related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your xhtml to and it works. I changed type of button as button instead of default submit. i also changed body to h:body. You can keep panelGroup or use panelGrid like me.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function testfunc() {
      document.getElementById("testForm:test").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("testForm:test").style.visibility="visible";
    }
   function hidefunc() {
     document.getElementById("testForm:test").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("testForm:test").style.visibility="hidden";
   }
    </script>
</head>

<h:body>

  <h:form id = "testForm" >
      <h:panelGrid id="test" style="display:none" >
        <h:commandLink value="Page 1" action="page1" /><br/>
       </h:panelGrid>
       <button onclick="testfunc()" type="button">Show me</button>
       <button onclick="hidefunc()" type="button">Hide me</button>
     </h:form> 

    </h:body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yeah, Great  Mahendran!  Thank you very much!

Comment: can u choose my answer with the green tick u see below triangle, and possibly upvote it.

Comment: I have chosen your answer. :)  upvote it- how to do it? I just vote - answer with the highest score first. Is it right?

Comment: click the triangle above the 0.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar: Please use 'you' instead of 'u', this is not whatsapp but a professional support environment

Comment: @Kukeltje okay. Will do

Comment: And are all the 'upvotes' on the comments by Leo from you?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes. Is there a rule for that too? i thought that was my prerogative

Comment: Well yes and no... But just 'upvoting' a 'thanks' comment directed at you or a statement that your answer was accepted is kind of weird (as are the two upvotes above). You e.g. should upvote a comment by someone else than the original poster that a better example should be provided, or that a suggestion by someone else is given to try a specific thing (before he/she is providing an answer). And you should in those cases not 'hijack' the question by providing an answer directly if someone else is trying to find a couse. All 'courtesy' things

Comment: i do not understand "And you should in those cases not 'hijack' the question by providing an answer directly if someone else is trying to find a couse." start a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95598/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-mahendran-ayyarsamy-kandiar).